# Eevee : Texture does not work as Glass Material

Tags: materials, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I have a cube and a textured plane behind a glass material.
The cube does show up but not the texture.

[image]

Any clues of what it could be ?

Comment: Try set the transparency mode to masked. I’m not at home so I can't take a screen shot of the setting, sorry. Refraction shaders reads the scene from all solids and not any translucent  materials. Masked transparency can be treated as solid.

Comment: are you using any light probe? and also, can you provide the .blend file?